# AS NoClassDefFoundError In new Moudle

Tags: java, android, junit, android-espresso

I create a new module In Android Studio, then add some dependencies in gradle.here is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.freddy.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'

    // Required -- JUnit 4 framework
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Optional -- Mockito framework
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    // Set this dependency to use JUnit 4 rules
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    // Set this dependency to build and run Espresso tests
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    //RecycleViews Espresso supports
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'design'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    // Set this dependency to build and run UI Automator tests
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.1'
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
```

then I create a `MainActivityTest` class under the androidTest/java/com/example/freddy/myapplication:

```
package com.example.freddy.myapplication;
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

/**
 * Created by freddy on 2016/11/30.
 */
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void testTextView(){
        onView(withId(R.id.tv_text)).check(matches(withText("Hello World!")));
    }
}
```

when I run the test,errors come cross

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.freddy.myapplication.MainActivity
at com.example.freddy.myapplication.MainActivityTest.<init>(MainActivityTest.java:22)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)

Tests ran to completion.
```

Is anybody has the same problem?

I've found that when I comment these code

```
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);
```

and delete

```
onView(withId(R.id.tv_text)).check(matches(withText("Hello World!")));
```

then run the test, everything is fine.Just can't load MainActivity.but actually, MainActivity is under main/java/com/example/freddy/myapplication, when I use `@Rule` just can't load it.

Comment: did you make sure before creating the Test class the `MainActivity` was already existing?

Comment: I am sure, MainActivity is there.

Comment: are these your unit tests or integration tests?

Comment: I use espresso to test ui

Comment: MainActivity defalut extends AppCompatActivity, I change it to Activity, then run test, everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Following the link from [developer.android](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html), the source says to create the Tests classes inside the src/test directory for unit tests -

> In your Android Studio project, you must store the source files for
>   local unit tests at ***module-name/src/test/java/***. This directory already
>   exists when you create a new project.

Also before executing the tests, please make sure the project is synced.(from the same link)

> Be sure your project is synchronized with Gradle by clicking Sync
>   Project  in the toolbar.

For the [UI-testing](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/index.html) part you shall add your tests to

> To automate UI tests with Android Studio, you implement your test code
>   in a separate Android test folder (***src/androidTest/java***)

Comment: I know , so I add my code under src/androidTest/java, cause I will do the UI-testing